# Intel Pin memory operations tracking

Tags: disassembly, binary-analysis, memory, pintool

I am using Intel Pin in order trace memory activity of an executable on Windows. What I have found, that most of the memory operands (Read or Write) operates with 2 or 4 bytes. So I decided to modify original Pin's *[pinatrace](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/71313/Pin/html/index.html#MAddressTrace)* example, in order to see which Assembly opcodes produces which memory activity.

```
VOID Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v)
{

        UINT32 memOperands = INS_MemoryOperandCount(ins);
        fprintf(trace,"\n[%s]\n",(INS_Disassemble(ins)).c_str()); 
        for (UINT32 memOp = 0; memOp < memOperands; memOp++)
        { 
             .....
```

What it basically does (I hope), is just writes disassembled opcode BEFORE the memory operands it produces. But then I looked in the file (W is for write, R is for read):

> [test edx, 0x800000]
>
> [jnz 0x77708557]
>
> [mov dword ptr [ebp-0x4], edi]
>
> [test dl, 0x1]
>
> [jnz 0x77703136] RWWRWW
>
> [lea edi, ptr [ebx+0xcc]]
>
> [push dword ptr [edi]]
>
> [call 0x77702520] RWW
>
> [mov edi, edi]
>
> [push ebp]
>
> [mov ebp, esp]
>
> [mov eax, dword ptr [ebp+0x8]]
>
> [mov ecx, dword ptr fs:[0x18]]
>
> [lea edx, ptr [eax+0x4]]
>
> [lock btr dword ptr [edx], 0x0]
>
> [jnb 0x777041dc]
>
> [mov ecx, dword ptr [ecx+0x24]]
>
> [mov dword ptr [eax+0xc], ecx]
>
> [mov dword ptr [eax+0x8], 0x1]
>
> [mov eax, 0x1]
>
> [pop ebp]
>
> [ret 0x4] WRRRWRWWRR

As we can see, opcodes that are supposed to work with memory (e.g. *mov*) do not produce memory operands. While memory traces are connected as blocks after **ret/call/jnz** etc.

**Question**: What kind of memory operands does Intel Pin trace? Is it about calls to virtual memory/RAM/CPU registers? Could it be possible, that memory activity goes in blocks due to CPU's pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally I came up with the solution that works how I want and results seem to be valid according to [this reference of instruction tables](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf)

```
fprintf(trace,"\n[%s]\n",(INS_Disassemble(ins)).c_str()); //(INS_Disassemble(ins)).c_str()
fflush(trace);
   
for (UINT32 memOp = 0; memOp < memOperands; memOp++)
{
    if (INS_MemoryOperandIsRead(ins, memOp))
    {
        fprintf(trace,"R");
        icount++;
    }

    if (INS_MemoryOperandIsWritten(ins, memOp))
    {
        fprintf(trace,"W");
        icount++;
    }
}
```

And it produces the following output:

```
[mov eax, dword ptr [ebp+0x10]]
R
[mov byte ptr [ebx+0x2], 0x0]
W
[mov byte ptr [ebx+0x7], 0x0]
W
```

I cannot be sure that it is the true sequence of executable under analysis because I do output in the instrumentation phase, but the code can probably be modified it the way to write opcode inside another  INS_InsertPredicatedCall, so it will be recorded when it will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit your print-out to just memory read/write instructions, your `fprintf()` needs to be inside the `if (INS_MemoryOperandIsRead(ins, memOp)) { ... }` block and inside the `if (INS_MemoryOperandIsWritten(ins, memOp)) { ... }` block (and you'll need to include some logic to not print the same instruction more than once).

For example:

```
// Is called for every instruction and instruments reads and writes
VOID Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v)
{
    // Instruments memory accesses using a predicated call, i.e.
    // the instrumentation is called iff the instruction will actually be executed.
    //
    // On the IA-32 and Intel(R) 64 architectures conditional moves and REP 
    // prefixed instructions appear as predicated instructions in Pin.
    UINT32 memOperands = INS_MemoryOperandCount(ins);

    BOOL printed = FALSE;

    // Iterate over each memory operand of the instruction.
    for (UINT32 memOp = 0; memOp < memOperands; memOp++)
    {
        if (INS_MemoryOperandIsRead(ins, memOp))
        {
            if (!printed)
            {
                fprintf(trace,"\n[%s]\n",(INS_Disassemble(ins)).c_str()); 
                printed = TRUE;
            }

            INS_InsertPredicatedCall(
                ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)RecordMemRead,
                IARG_INST_PTR,
                IARG_MEMORYOP_EA, memOp,
                IARG_END);
        }
        // Note that in some architectures a single memory operand can be 
        // both read and written (for instance incl (%eax) on IA-32)
        // In that case we instrument it once for read and once for write.
        if (INS_MemoryOperandIsWritten(ins, memOp))
        {
            if (!printed)
            {
                fprintf(trace,"\n[%s]\n",(INS_Disassemble(ins)).c_str()); 
                printed = TRUE;
            }

            INS_InsertPredicatedCall(
                ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)RecordMemWrite,
                IARG_INST_PTR,
                IARG_MEMORYOP_EA, memOp,
                IARG_END);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion. But when I tried I received the following:

> [pop ebx]
> 
> [pop edi]
> 
> [pop esi]
> 
> [pop ebp]
> 
> [ret 0x10] 
> 
> RRRRR
> 
> [mov byte ptr [ebp-0x19], al]
> 
> [mov dword ptr [ebp-0x4], ebx]
> 
> [call 0x7770c290] 
> 
> WWW 
> 
> [call 0x776f2165]  
> 
> W  
> 
> [push ebp]
> 
> [mov eax, dword ptr fs:[0x18]]

Comment: Well, comment formatting doesn't work well, but as you can see - there are still opcodes with no memory operations.

Do you exactly know what kind of *memory operations* (to what kind of *memory*) Pin traces?

Comment: Every instruction you printed above does indeed involve a memory read or write. `pop`s and `ret`s read from the stack memory, the `mov`s write to memory, the `call`s read from memory, and the `push` writes to the stack memory.

Comment: Allright, thank you. But they all work with data stored in RAM (not taking CPU's cache into account, since pages are synchronized), am I right? And why there is no read operations after `calls` so far?